# Как проверять зареган ли пользователь next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, nextjs

В куках у меня хранится токен. Каждый раз при рендеринге страницы я достаю токен оттуда, дешифрую его и заношу в стор данные рользователя.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps((store) => async (ctx) => {

const {token} = nookies.get(ctx)

if (token) {
    const {email, name}: IUser = jwt_decode(token)
    store.dispatch(setUser({email, name}))
}

const {data} = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/post`)

return {
    props: {
        data
    }
}
```

})
Как сделать чтобы не осуществлять эту проверку на каждой странице ?

Comment: Может быть выполнять эту проверку в _app.js ?

Comment: А каким образом?

Comment: nextauth в помощь